# Unity and C#, event registration failing. No argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Haven't done Unity nor C# in a long time and instead of implementing the observer pattern myself I decided to use delegates and event type to register catch changes in a object. I'm also trying to follow MVC.

Tile.cs

```
private delegate void TileTypeChanged(Tile tile);
public event TileTypeChanged TileTypeChangedEvent;

public TileType Type {
    get
    {
        return type;
    }        
    set
    {
        type = value;
        if(TileTypeChangedEvent != null)
        {
            TileTypeChangedEvent(this);

        }
    }
}
```

WorldController.cs

```
Tile tile = GameWorld.Tiles[x,y];        
GameObject tileGameObject = new GameObject();
...
tile.TileTypeChangedEvent += OnTileTypeChanged( (tileRef) => {OnTileTypeChanged(tileRef, tileGameObject); });


void OnTileTypeChanged(Tile tile, GameObject tileGameObject)
{
    if(tile.Type == Tile.TileType.Floor)
    {
        tileGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = FloorSprite;
    }
    else
    {
        tileGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = null;
    }
}
```

The errors I get are:

1. There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'tileGameObject' of 'WorldController.OnTileTypeChanged(Tile, GameObject)'

This I don't understand, I am basically calling the OnTileTypeChanged() using a lambda expression in WorldController.cs with a tileGameObject argument assigned a value before but still it throws an error

2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Tile.TileTypeChanged'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
OnTileTypeChanged( (tileRef) => {OnTileTypeChanged(tileRef, tileGameObject); });
```

makes no sense .. you are trying to pass a lambda expression in as parameter.

I guess you tried to rather use

```
tile.TileTypeChangedEvent += tileRef => OnTileTypeChanged(tileRef, tileGameObject);
```

---

Also

```
private delegate void TileTypeChanged(Tile tile);
public event TileTypeChanged TileTypeChangedEvent;
```

if `TileTypeChangedEvent` is `public` then its type `TileTypeChanged` should also be `public`.

You could btw also simply use

```
public event Action<Tile> TileTypeChangedEvent;
```

but that's probably a matter of taste.

---

The check

```
if(TileTypeChangedEvent != null)
{
    TileTypeChangedEvent(this);
}
```

can be simplified to

```
TileTypeChangedEvent?.Invoke(this);
```

see [`?.` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it, I though the first piece of code would call the method, create an anonymous function and run it after/inside the OnTileTypeChanged but now it makes no sense at all. So the changes you made is that an anonymous function is registered which calls the OnTileTypeChanged()